# Get data from ViewModel after setting up the observer

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a fragment, which contains `LiveData`, and `SwiperRefreshLauout`. In `onCreateView` I have set the observer for some String.

User, while playing with fragment, can change the value of this string, but it should be only temporary. Whenever user will trigger `onRefreshListener`, the String should get "default" data, that came from observer.

I'd like to know, if there's any way to call data from observer again, in `onRefreshListener`, or I have to remove observer from `onCreateView`, and make another one after `onRefreshListener` is called?

Dummy scenario:

We have String, called test. In `OnCreateView`, we are setting the observer to the `ViewModel`, and get some data from database to the test string. Let's say it'll be name - "Mark". When user will pick from spinner another name: "Carl" the test string will have value of "Carl" now. User would like to refresh the UI of layout, and now, the test string should have value - "Mark" again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, here I have a suggestion:

- In the onCreateView setup an observer of your live data, `viewModel.data.observe(...)`
- At the same time you could call the function responsible for fetching the data, `viewModel.fetchData("initialValue")`. On the other hand, since this is the initial call, you could use the `init` section of the View Model class and call there the initial fetch. `init { fetchData("initialValue") }`
- Then, everytime the pull to refresh callback is executed, inside the `onRefresh` you could call the function to fetch the data, but this time with the temp value `viewModel.fetchData("defaultValue")`

So, everytime you call the `viewModel.fetchData("anyValue")` the `data` LiveData will be refreshed and since you are already subscribed in the `onCreateView` then you will receive the updates there.

if this is not clear, please share some code in this way, I can give better advise.